# Change order of items when the bootstrap navbar is opened

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

On a Tablet resolution (wide) I want that the "Anmelden" and "Registrieren" button appears on the very right side but on a smartphone resolution both items should stay at the top of the menu (see image)

How can I do that preferably without javascript?

[image]

Here is a plunker (not mine) where you can try out:

http://plnkr.co/edit/58wuSb2d6ztwUhbA01Mt?p=preview

In the plunker the buttons are called "Login" and "Register" not like on my screenshot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>

    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js" data-semver="1.1.5"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@0.5.0" data-semver="0.5.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <style>
    div.navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-height: 0px;
        -webkit-transition: max-height .3s ease;
        -moz-transition: max-height .3s ease;
        -o-transition: max-height .3s ease;
        transition: max-height .3s ease;
    }
    div.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
        max-height: 2000px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-init="navCollapsed = true" ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Login</a>
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Register</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" ng-class="!navCollapsed && 'in'">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Meine Geräte</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Konfiguration</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">..::TEST::..</a></li>

        </ul>

      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: without javascript hmm you can create different menus and use the classes  to show them depending on what screen you are on. (sr-only), that's the first thing that came to my mind. I am sure there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could make this thing for have a rapid order menu without js

```
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-init="navCollapsed = true" ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm" href="#">Login</a>
     <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm" href="#">Register</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" ng-class="!navCollapsed && 'in'">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Meine Geräte</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Konfiguration</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">..::TEST::..</a></li>

    </ul>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-lg hidden-xs hidden-md">
     <li><a class="" href="#">Login</a></li>
     <li><a class="" href="#">Register</a></li>
  </ul>

  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```